# Assign an object to the class from within

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using LINQ to Get data from database table called table1
when using LINQ a class called table1 was created

i created a partial class to add functionality to table1 class

```
public partial class Table1
{
public Table1(int id)
{
    using (DBDataContext item = new DBDataContext())
        {
            var q = (from c in item.table1
                     where c.ID == id
                     select c).FirstOrDefault();
        }
}
}
```

now i want to assign the result "q" to the current object
do i need to assign it's properties one by one ?
or is there something faster??

Comment: You're missing too many details here. What you have doesn't make sense and won't compile at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to assign it property by property, cause the result of your query *is not* an object, but `IEnumerable<..something..>` of something. So you need to iterate over collection of values and assign them to corresponding properties of the object.

**EDIT**

At this point *I would* do, like this:

```
public static Table1 TableFromId(int Id)
{
     using (DBDataContext item = new DBDataContext())
        {
            return  (from c in item.table1
                     where c.ID == id
                     select c).FirstOrDefault() as Table1;
        }
}
```

and after use

```
Table1 table = Table1.TableFromId(0);
```

Comment: I used FirstOrDefault()
- which will return an object type Table1

Comment: The OP calls `FirstOrDefault()` which returns an object, not an enumeration!

Comment: @Star: ok, at this point 1. I would make the method a `static` and *not* ctor. After will create a new `Table1` object and return.

Comment: that's what i was doing but i thought maybe the is something better

Comment: @Star: I edeited my post to clarify. You do not use a `static` method, but `ctor`, it's a different.

Comment: - I know i'm using ctor here 
- i meant i did that before 
any way i will use static method

Comment: @Star: In *my* opinion this is a clearest solution. If not, you need to deal with single property assignment.

Answer (score 1):

What I will usually do is have my business object or view model have a contructor that takes in the "DTO" as a parameter and sets the properties of the object from the DTO.      You could also create a mapper to do so.

I'd say that the query itself and database access should be in a seperate "Repository" class or data access layer, not in your object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Implement an `ICopyable` interface and copy from an object similar to this.

```
public class Person: ICopyable<Person>
{
    public string Name {set; get;}
    public int Age {set; get;}

    public void  CopyFrom(Person otherObject)
    {
        if (otherObject != null)
        {
            Name = otherObject.Name;
            Age = otherObject.Age;
        }
    }

    public Table1(int id)
    {
        using (DBDataContext item = new DBDataContext())
        {
            var q = (from c in item.table1
                 where c.ID == id
                 select c).FirstOrDefault() as Person;
            if (q != null)
            {
                CopyFrom(q);
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface ICopyable<TType>
{
    void CopyFrom(TType otherObject);
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding but with this is the I will still need to assign it one by one

Comment: otherwise you'll need reflection which is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refactor your code and to create a static method, which returns the required object directly. I assume that your query returns an object of type `Table1`.

```
public partial class Table1
{
     public static FromID(int id)
     {
         using (var context = new DBDataContext()) {
            return (Table1)(from c in context.table1
                            where c.ID == id
                            select c).FirstOrDefault();
         }
     }
}
```

Then you can get a new object with

```
Table1 obj = Table1.FromID(17);
```

---

**Note**: Since your query returns a `Table1` object, there is no point in creating a new `Table1` object and assigning it the properties of the object returned by the query. Use the object returned by the query directly! Therefore you will need a static method, which can be called without instantiating the class.